Function $f$ is defined by $f(x)=-x^2$. Function $g$ is obtained by reflecting the graph of $f$ across the line $y=1$. Find $g(4)$
I have the answer, but I am interested in the process by which it is obtained because in the textbooks I've used, they tend not to have questions such as this one. I find this question rather tricky.
If I were to find another questions like this say instead of $f(x)$ being reflected across the $y$-axis at 1, it says instead, it's reflected across the y-axis at 3. Would the answer be 22, in that case.
The limit for the question field for this post restricted me to a truncated version of the question. I've attached a screenshot of the question below to more fully illustrate the context of the problem.


Can you not move the entire function down 1 unit to make the reflecting line $y=0$ and then do a fairly standard reflection in the $x$-axis? If so, this would work for $y=k$ as well.

A more general case of reflecting in any line is given here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1404960/reflecting-a-function-about-a-line?rq=1

The way that I might approach this problem is to try and determine what the graph would look like after flipping it over the line $y=1$. Since the vertex of $f$ is at $(0,0)$, the vertex of $g$ must be at $(0,2)$. Then, I might ask myself what the function $g$ would be algebraically. Since $g$ is an upward facing parabola, and its vertex is at $(0,2)$, the graph of $g$ must be $g(x)=x^2+2$. Then find $g(4)$ from here, by plugging $4$ in.

BSplitter's answer provides complete information about the function $g$, but if you only want to determine $g(4)$, then here's an alternative approach. First, note that reflection in a horizontal line won't change the $x$-coordinate of a point, so, since we want a point on the graph of $g$ with $x$-coordinate $4$, we should find the point on the graph of $f$ with $x$-coordinate $4$. The formula for $f$ says that is $(4,-16)$, which is $17$ units below the reflection line $y=1$. So its reflection, on the graph of $g$, will be $17$ ubits above that line, i.e., at height $18$.

Since no one else directly mentioned composition of functions as such, although that is the foundation of the answer of c'est pas normale, I will write such an answer.
$~f(x) = -(x^2).~$
Let $~g(x)~$ represent reflection across the line $~y = 1.~$
Then:

$~g(1) = 1 = (2 - 1).$

$g(x) = 1 - (x - 1) = 2 - x ~: ~x > 1.$

$g(x) = 1 + (1 - x) = 2 - x ~: x < 0.$


So, $~g(x) = (2 - x),~$ for all $~x.~$
Therefore, $~g[f(x)] = g[ ~-(x^2) ~] = 2 - [ ~-(x^2) ~] = 2 + x^2.$
Therefore, $~g[f(4)] = 2 + 4^2.$

$$\Large \color{red}{g(4)=2\cdot1-f(4)=2+4^2=18}$$
The reflection of $y=f(x)$ over the line $y=k$ is equivalent to the reflection over the $x-$axis ($y\rightarrow-y$), followed by the translation upwards with $2k$ units ($-y\rightarrow-y+2k$).
$$\large y=f(x)=-x^2\xrightarrow[\text{over}~\color{red}{y=1}]{\text{Reflection}}\color{red}{(2\cdot1-y)}=-x^2\implies \color{red}{y=g(x)=x^2+2}$$
So,
$$\Large \color{red}{\boxed{g(4)=4^2+2=18}}$$
